# Linq OrderByDescending but keep zero value first

Tags: linq

I have a collection of integers that I want to order by descending value, with the exception of keeping a 0 value as first in the list.

For example:
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8

Should result in:
0,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1

Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

```
var input = new [] {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
```

Two sortings which work with both negative and positive numbers:

```
var result = input.OrderBy(i => i == 0? 0 : 1).ThenByDescending(i => i);
```

or this if all your numbers are non-negative:

```
var result = input.OrderByDescending(i => i == 0? int.MaxValue : i);
```

or some really weird solution if you have both negative and positive numbers but you don't want to sort twice (as I'm doing in first solution):

```
var result = input
              .GroupBy(i => i == 0 ? 0 : 1)
              .OrderBy(g => g.Key)
              .Select(g => g.Key == 0 ? g : g.OrderByDescending(i => i)
              .SelectMany(g => g);
```

Comment: Very nice.  I knew somebody would have an elegant solution.

Comment: Or to convert it to the equivalent LINQ statement: `from i in input orderby i == 0 ? 0 : 1, i descending`.